# Convert Set[Strings] to JSON String scala

Tags: json, scala, set, scala-collections

Convert Set[Strings] to JSON String using scala programming.
Eg :

```
data = Set(Client_1, Client_2, Client_3)
```

I am trying as below,

```
   val toString : String = new Gson().toJson(data)
```

which returns an empty.How to convert using scala ?

Comment: Googling *scala collection to json* yields several options right off the bat with different tools, json4s, play framework json parser and spray-json, to name but a few.

Comment: Is it not possible to convert without using any framework like play , spary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson is a library for Java, not for Scala, subsequently it doesn't always  handle Scala collections correctly. It may indeed make sense (as others have suggested) to use a JSON framework made for Scala instead.

However you can also simply use the [Java conversions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) to get a Java collection and pass that to your Gson instance, like this:

```
import collection.JavaConverters.setAsJavaSetConverter

val input: java.util.Set[String] = Set("foo", "bar", "baz").asJava
val json: String = new Gson().toJson(input) // ["foo","bar","baz"]
```

Or just instantiate a Java collection in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Gson/Fasterxml can not process scala collection types correctly,convert to java collections first.
You can invoke scala.collection.JavaConversions.setAsJavaSet(data) to get a java collection then use gson to convert it